# Call an async method on pageload and wait for to complete the execution - c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, datarow

I want to call a web api method on page load event of my project. But I want to wait for the execution of the function 'GetSelectedTaskDetails' to complete. So that I can manage with the values from DataRow row.
Could you please suggest how can i achieve this?

```
  private DataRow row;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   GetSelectedTaskDetails(Id);
  //other codes
 }
   private async void GetSelectedTaskDetails(int? selected_task_id)
   {
    try
    {
        url = baseUrl + "GetSelectedTaskDetails?task_id=" + selected_task_id;
        using (var objClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await objClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if ((int)response.StatusCode == 401)//unauthorised or token expired
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var GetResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(GetResponse);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        row = dt.Rows[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ex.Message.ToString());
        var script = string.Format("alert({0});", message);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "", script, true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Change `Page_Load` signature from `void` to `async void`, change `async void GetSelectedTaskDetails` to `async Task GetSelectedTaskDetails(int? selected_task_id)` then do `await GetSelectedTaskDetails(Id);`.

Comment: @WSC that won't really work either - the thing that *calls* `Page_Load` won't have any way of knowing when it has completed

Comment: @MarcGravell What do you mean? `Page_Load` is clearly an event which can (and should, if it's calling async methods) be `async void` which can then await `GetSelectedTaskDetails`. See Stephen Cleary's answer for the same thing.

Comment: @WSC that usage with event handlers works much better in client UI code where the form (or whatever) is likely to still be around when the async code finishes. The fact remains that in this scenario, the server code will have no clue whether/when this code has completed. If the response goes to the client before then: tough, there's no longer a request to do anything more with.

Answer (score 5):

You should [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) - it's intended for event handlers. So `GetSelectedTaskDetails` should be `async Task` instead of `async void`. Once `GetSelectedTaskDetails` is properly returning a `Task`, you can `await` it in your `Page_Load`:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await GetSelectedTaskDetails(Id);
  ...
}
```

Note that for `async` to work properly on ASP.NET pre-Core, you need to [set `Page.Async` to `true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) and ensure [`httpRuntime@targetFramework` is set to 4.5 or newer in your `web.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#before-getting-started)

Comment: Arguably, when `async void` is involved, it can never work "properly" as there is no way for the server to know what is going on in terms of life cycle of the request versus the async flow.

Comment: @MarcGravell: This is code that lives in the ancient days of ASP.NET, where the `AspNetSynchronizationContext` keeps track of the number of `async void` methods. `async void` method builders call `SynchronizationContext.OperationStarted` and `OperationCompleted`, and `AspNetSynchronizationContext` listens to these so it is aware of incomplete `async void`  calls.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I seem to recall the legacy asp-net sync-context simply threw an exception in this path; I distinctly remember having to remove async void (fire and forget) from some libraries (mostly SE-Redis) because that sync-context was barfing...

Comment: Worse: it seems like it is fussy about *exactly when* it will or won't allow async void: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/AspNetSynchronizationContext.cs,108

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yup, that's why there's three parts to the answer. `async void` is allowed for `Page_Load` - *if* you've set `Page.Async` to `true` *and* enabled the non-legacy ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` (e.g., via `httpRuntime.targetFramework`). Unfortunately convoluted, yet an impressive level of support for a technology as old as WebForms.

Comment: @StephenCleary it works only for httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  or higher. Is there any way to run it on versions below 4.5?

Comment: @user2431727: No. You cannot use `async` on ASP.NET before 4.5.